# How to add Speech Recognition to Unity project?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, speech-recognition, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am presently working on a Augmented Reality project using Vuforia that uses Speech recognition to control the objects in Unity. I was just looking for a sample working code.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unity does not have this built in yet. They have been doing [research](https://labs.unity.com/article/speech-recognition-and-vr) on it for a long time and this will likely be added into Unity very soon. You can get the working Speech-to-Text(free) from the Assets store [here](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/69399). It is open source and you can help [contribute](https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/speech-to-text) to it if you find any problems.

As a side note, almost every OS has a Speech Recognition API. You easily make a plugin by wrapping all those API into a sing class in C# then use [Unity's platform preprocessor directives](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html) to determine which one to call depending on which OS your game is running on.

**Android**:

[SpeechRecognizer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html) class.

see this project https://github.com/gsssrao/UnityAndroidSpeechRecognition

**iOS**:

[SFSpeechRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/speech/sfspeechrecognizer) class

**MacOS**:

[NSSpeechRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsspeechrecognizer) class

**Windows**:

[SpeechRecognitionEngine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine(v=vs.110).aspx) class

see this project https://github.com/LightBuzz/Speech-Recognition-Unity

Example:

```
class CrazySpeechRecognition
{
  #if UNITY_ANDROID  
    Use SpeechRecognizer class
  #endif

  #if UNITY_IOS
    Use SFSpeechRecognizer class
  #endif

  #if UNITY_STANDALONE_OSX || UNITY_EDITOR_OSX
    Use NSSpeechRecognizer class
  #endif

  #if UNITY_STANDALONE_WIN || UNITY_EDITOR_WIN
    Use SpeechRecognitionEngine class
  #endif 
}
```

The free [Speech-to-Text](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/69399) from Unity is sadly discontinued, as stated in the link.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :-)

Comment: The Speech to text package contains many errors

Comment: That Speech-to-Text package you linked to has been removed by unity.

Comment: @UpTheCreek Not sure why and when they removed those links but they can still obtain it from the contribute link I provided in the answer too.

Answer (score 2):

You can try Watson Unity SDK: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk^ in particular ExampleSpeechToText

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex! Will try it out!

Comment: Hi, Does there is any speech to text standalone sdk available, which is not using any third party API ? Thanks