# Use Windows Speech Recognition API in Unity

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, dll

I am trying to add System.Speech.dll to my Unity project but I get System.BadImageFormatException. I am using a 64 bit Windows 10. The build setting is set for x86_64 and the scripting runtime version I am using is ".Net 4.x equivalent".

That .dll I got it from "Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6". What it is interesting is in MS Visual Studio it actually detect that dll and I can write: using System.Speech but Unity does not want to accept that .dll. I look over different posts but nothing worked for me. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `System.Speech.dll` and there are many issues that comes with it because it it using Mono. Just import the `UnityEngine.Windows.Speech` namespace an you should be good to go. This requires *Unity 5.4.0b2* and above to work on Windows.

You have different types of spech API such as [`DictationRecognizer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Windows.Speech.DictationRecognizer.html),[`GrammarRecognizer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Windows.Speech.GrammarRecognizer.html), [`KeywordRecognizer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Windows.Speech.KeywordRecognizer.html), [`PhraseRecognitionSystem`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Windows.Speech.PhraseRecognitionSystem.html), and [`PhraseRecognizer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Windows.Speech.PhraseRecognizer.html). The doc has many examples on how to use each one.

Below is an example of the [`KeywordRecognizer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Windows.Speech.KeywordRecognizer.html) from the doc:

```
[SerializeField]
private string[] m_Keywords;

private KeywordRecognizer m_Recognizer;

void Start()
{
    m_Recognizer = new KeywordRecognizer(m_Keywords);
    m_Recognizer.OnPhraseRecognized += OnPhraseRecognized;
    m_Recognizer.Start();
}

private void OnPhraseRecognized(PhraseRecognizedEventArgs args)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.AppendFormat("{0} ({1}){2}", args.text, args.confidence, Environment.NewLine);
    builder.AppendFormat("\tTimestamp: {0}{1}", args.phraseStartTime, Environment.NewLine);
    builder.AppendFormat("\tDuration: {0} seconds{1}", args.phraseDuration.TotalSeconds, Environment.NewLine);
    Debug.Log(builder.ToString());
}
```

This is for *Windows* only since you're targeting Window-64 bit. For other platforms, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39611728/how-to-add-speech-recognition-to-unity-project/39613264#39613264) post.

Comment: UnityEngine.Windows.Speech only supports Speech recogniton and not speech synthesis. System.Speech supports both.

Comment: @Haydn If that's the case then create your own plugin. I linked to nother post of which API to use

Comment: System.Speech is the only one with Viseme information and is free. Viseme's is why I want to use it.  I tried to using System.Speech from a plugin, but unity just disables the plugin.