# Call Functions on Voice Commands In Android Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, voice-recognition

I am making a flashlight application in unity C#. The application is almost complete I just want to add this voice command feature in this like when I say "ON" the flashlight should turn on and when I say " OFF " the flashlight should turn off. The application is for Android devices. I saw several tutorials about calling functions on voice commands but that all were only for windows platform please help me if you know something about doing this in android thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not used any Speech Recognition tools but its not very difficult to implement if you can create a java plugin & use it to call native function. Anyways I have found few of the SDK:

---

You can check out the pocket sphinx demos for speech recognition.

https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx

https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-android-demo

---

Here is a repo I found which uses AndroidSpeechRecognition.

https://github.com/gsssrao/UnityAndroidSpeechRecognition

---

Programmer has given a nice explaination of voice recognition implementation natively:

[How to add Speech Recognition to Unity project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39611728/how-to-add-speech-recognition-to-unity-project)

---

Then there is WatsonSDK for unity but it seems to be via cloud but you can check this one out:
https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk

---

And if you dont mind paying for this plugin called Android SpeakNow you can grab it from asset store:
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/android-speaknow-16781

---

These are some cloud based packages from asset store, I really doubt you might need this one to implement but in any case this is for someone who may require them at some point of time:

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/add-ons/machinelearning/google-cloud-speech-recognition-vr-ar-desktop-desktop-72625

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/yandex-cloud-speech-recognition-vr-ar-mobile-desktop-75155

---

And finally [DictationRecognizer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Windows.Speech.DictationRecognizer.html); by default this one is available only for windows 10 as of Unity 2018.2. So this is out of question. My best bet would be **cmusphinx** or **implementing natively** which I believe would be more suitable for your needs. Check them out. Try to implement one or two and let us know if you were successful or not.

If anyone can add more links to SDK for voice recognition feel free to add. This would be really great.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need only ON and OFF voice inputs you can use the following code

[Speech to text in unity](https://github.com/codemaker2015/Speech-to-text--STT--in-unity)

If you need exact speech recognition then refer the following code

[Speech recognition in unity](https://github.com/gsssrao/UnityAndroidSpeechRecognition)