# In Unity, how to segment the user's voice from microphone based on loudness?

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio-recording

I need to collect voice pieces from a continuous audio stream. I need to process later the user's voice piece that has just been said (not for speech recognition). What I am focusing on is only the voice's segmentation based on its loudness.

If after at least 1 second of silence, his voice becomes loud enough for a while, and then silent again for at least 1 second, I say this is a sentence and the voice should be segmented here.

I just know I can get raw audio data from the `AudioClip` created by `Microphone.Start()`. I want to write some code like this:

```
void Start()
{
    audio = Microphone.Start(deviceName, true, 10, 16000);
}

void Update()
{
    audio.GetData(fdata, 0);
    for(int i = 0; i < fdata.Length; i++) {
        u16data[i] = Convert.ToUInt16(fdata[i] * 65535);
    }
    // ... Process u16data
}
```

But what I'm not sure is:

1. Every frame when I call `audio.GetData(fdata, 0)`, what I get is the latest 10 seconds of sound data if `fdata` is big enough or shorter than 10 seconds if `fdata` is not big enough, is it right?
2. `fdata` is a float array, and what I need is a 16 kHz, 16 bit PCM buffer. Is it right to convert the data like: `u16data[i] = fdata[i] * 65535`?
3. What is the right way to detect loud moments and silent moments in `fdata`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add Speech Recognition to Unity project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39611728/how-to-add-speech-recognition-to-unity-project)

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad Thanks for reminding. I have modified this question. In fact I am not focusing on speech recognition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No. you have to read starting at the current position within the `AudioClip` using [`Microphone.GetPosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Microphone.GetPosition.html)

   > Get the position in samples of the recording.

   and pass the optained index to  [`AudioClip.GetData`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioClip.GetData.html)

   > Use the offsetSamples parameter to start the read from a specific position in the clip

   ```c#
   fdata = new float[clip.samples * clip.channels];

   var currentIndex = Microphone.GetPosition(null);
   audio.GetData(fdata, currentIndex);
   ```
2. I don't understand what exactly you convert this for. `fdata` will contain

   > floats ranging from `-1.0f` to `1.0f` ([`AudioClip.GetData`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioClip.GetData.html))

   so if for some reason you need to get values between [`short.MinValue` (= -32768)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.int16.minvalue) and [`short.MaxValue`(= 32767)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.int16.maxvalue) than yes you **can** do that using

   ```c#
   u16data[i] = Convert.ToUInt16(fdata[i] * short.MaxValue);
   ```

   note however that [`Convert.ToUInt16(float)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.convert.touint16#System_Convert_ToUInt16_System_Single_):

   > value, rounded to the nearest 16-bit unsigned integer. If value is halfway between two whole numbers, the even number is returned; that is, 4.5 is converted to 4, and 5.5 is converted to 6.

   you might want to rather use [Mathf.RoundToInt](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.RoundToInt.html) first to also round up if a value is e.g. `4.5`.

   ```c#
   u16data[i] = Convert.ToUInt16(Mathf.RoundToInt(fdata[i] * short.MaxValue));
   ```

   Your naming however suggests that you are actually trying to get unsigned values `ushort` (or also `UInt16`). For this you can **not** have **negative** values! So you have to shift the float values up in order to map the range (`-1.0f` | `1.0f` ) to the range (`0.0f` | `1.0f`) before multiplaying it by [`ushort.MaxValue`(= 65535)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.uint16.maxvalue)

   ```c#
   u16data[i] = Convert.ToUInt16(Mathf.RoundToInt(fdata[i] + 1) / 2 * ushort.MaxValue);
   ```
3. What you receive from [`AudioClip.GetData`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioClip.GetData.html) are the gain values of the audio track between `-1.0f` and `1.0f`.

   so a "loud" moment would be where

   ```c#
   Mathf.Abs(fdata[i]) >= aCertainLoudThreshold;
   ```

   a "silent" moment would be where

   ```c#
   Mathf.Abs(fdata[i]) <= aCertainSiltenThreshold;
   ```

where `aCertainSiltenThreshold` might e.g. be `0.2f` and `aCertainLoudThreshold` might e.g. be `0.8f`.

Comment: It's very helpful. Thank you so much.

Comment: I barely understand sound so I didn't know that sound data are actually signed. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome :) Usually sound is allways signed though I saw there are formats that use unsigned PCM 16 .. that's why I added both because I don't know what you needed exactly ;)